# vue-loader 15, webpack 4, vue-datepicker-local error running: npm run dev

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack

I am trying to update my app from using webpack2 to now use the new version of webpack4 and teh vue-loader 15, the process was smooth, but now I am facing an issue trying to generate the bundles

I am getting the next error running

```
npm run dev
```

get the next stack trace

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-datepicker-local/src/VueDatepickerLocal.vue 
1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <template>
| <div class="datepicker" :class="{'datepicker- 
range':range,'datepicker__clearable':clearable&&text&&!disabled}">
|   <input readonly :value="text" :class="[show ? 'focus' : '', 
inputClass]" :disabled="disabled" :placeholder="placeholder" 
:name="name" v-if="type!=='inline'"/>
@ ./node_modules/vue-datepicker-local/src/index.js 1:0-48 3:16-25 3:32- 
41 5:0-9 9:15-24
@ ./src/main/resources/static/app/js/sample/sample.js
@ multi 
./src/main/resources/static/app/js/scheduler/sample.js
```

I am using the next package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/main/resources/static/js/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --display-error-details",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --display-error-details ",
    "dev-watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
    "dev-watch-scheduler": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.dev.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "unit-watch": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@vue/cli": "^3.6.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "postcss": "^7.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "query-string": "^6.4.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "spin.js": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "svgxuse": "^1.2.6",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-datepicker-local": "^1.0.12",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-star-rating": "^1.6.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.1",
    "worker": "^0.3.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.27.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.14.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.2.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "raw-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "sinon": "^7.3.2",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.3.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

and the next wepack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, dir);
}

// Get appropriate environment.
const env = !process.env.NODE_ENV ? 'prod' : process.env.NODE_ENV;
const projectPath = process.cwd();

const miniCSSExtract = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: env === 'dev' ? '[name].bundle.css' : '[name].bundle-[contenthash].css',
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'app/js/sample-dev': ['@babel/polyfill', './src/main/resources/static/app/js/app/sample.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: `${__dirname}/target/classes/static/`,
  },
  mode: env === 'prod' ? 'production' : 'development',
  resolve: {
    aliasFields: ['browser'],
    alias: {
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    },
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.vue',
      '.scss',
      '.css',
    ],
  },
  devtool: env === 'dev'
    ? '#eval-source-map' /* internal, cheap, fast */
    : 'source-map' /* external */,

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              indentedSyntax: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        include: resolve('./src/main/resources/static/components/imgs'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        exclude: resolve('./src/main/resources/static/components/imgs'),
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"development"',
      },
    }),
    new ManifestPlugin(
      {
        fileName: 'outfitting/manifest.json',
      },
    ),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    miniCSSExtract,
  ]);
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // module.exports.devtool = '#source-map';
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: env === 'prod' ? '"production"' : '""',
      },
    }),
    // new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: env === 'prod',
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: env === 'prod',
      },
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    miniCSSExtract,
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
    }),
    new ManifestPlugin(
      {
        fileName: 'outfitting/manifest.json',
      },
    ),
  ]);
}
```

and in my sample.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import VueDatepickerLocal from 'vue-datepicker-local';
import store from './store';
import tooltip from './tooltip.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueDatepickerLocal);
Vue.component('tooltip', tooltip);

const routes = [
  { path: '/app/sample/', component: () => import('./sampleForm.vue') },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.commit('initialize');
  },
  render: h => h(app),
  router,
  store,
}).$mount('#app');
```

not sure what is happening, I cannot create the bundle files yet, I have tried different loaders with no success